Copy a folder to another drive by RIGHT-CLICKING on it in Windows 10
I want to be able to copy a Windows 10 folder by right-clicking on it and then selecting an option named "CopyFolderToCard".  (The card in question is the SD card that is currently serving as my D: drive.)
I want the folder moved with all its contents, including all files and folders, and I want the folder to have the same name as it originally did.
I've been able to move the contents of the folder itself. I have also been able to move a folder itself and its contents but the name gets changed.
Can anyone help me with this?  Please....
I've used Co-Pilot in an effort to solve my problem, but it keeps making the mistakes I've described.

Using what?  Are you asking about writing a Windows Explorer extension, or a script, or are you looking for a tool that someone else has written?  If developing it yourself see [ask], if looking for app help then [su] probably makes more sense than here.

I want to write my own tool.  I have created one that lets me move a single file to my SD card by right-clicking on the file and then choosing the "CopyFileToCard" option that I created.  It uses the following statement:  cmd.exe /c xcopy "%1" "D:\Copied Files" /i /s /y

Surely there is a similar command for moving folders in the manner I have described.  None of them seem to work, though.

Please edit your question to include more details then -- see How to Ask. Add the language (Command shell) and your code.

Is this what you are looking for?

There's an "edit" link at the bottom of your question.  You can use it to include the missing details.  It's best to include the details in the question itself not in a set of comments.

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes*\shell\CopyFileToCard\command
